# What is the coldfusion code to upload a file in amazon s3 api?

Tags: coldfusion, amazon-s3

I am having a problem trying to figure out what is the proper coldfusion code to upload a simple file into amazon s3 api.  Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3):

There is a good tutorial [here](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2010/7/15/CF901-Guide-to-Amazon-S3-support-in-ColdFusion-901). You'll need CF 9.0.1 however.

Prior to CF 9 you might be able to use [this](http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/projects/amazon-s3-cfc/) CFC that Barney Boisvert wrote.

Comment: thanks for the link but at my work we use CF 8 .. any suggestions?

Comment: Edited answer - lo and behold there is a CFC for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this CFC: http://amazons3.riaforge.org/

Also, note that you may also access your objects via:
http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/name-of-the-object (example)

Comment: I went to that site http://amazons3.riaforge.org/ was not really to useful for me, and the second link you provided comes up as "access denied".  But thank you for trying to help.

Comment: The second links was an example of how you can just directly link to S3 files once you've uploaded them - provided you've set the proper security.

Comment: Also, why wasn't the RIAforge.org content useful?

Comment: ok your right that makes sense in regards to the second link.  and I'm just not understanding the information on RIAforge.org, nothing against the site, I'm just having issues trying to find the simplest method to write out a code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset s3bucket = "s3://yourbuketname/">
<cffile action="upload" filefield="filename" destination="#s3bucket#" nameconflict="makeunique" charset="utf-8" />
```