# How to set input/output variables in ColdFusion for the following?

Tags: variables, coldfusion, input, amazon-s3

**how do I make the input/output variables in proper coldfusion code?**

Variables
        INPUT:
            variables.s3_target_directory
            variables.file_name
            variables.file_location

```
    OUTPUT:
        variables.success
        variables.transactionid / success UUID
        variables.s3_location   - link can be http or https
```

Comment: Poorly worded question, but I did my best to come up with an aswer for you...

Comment: looks like this is the same question asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196658/what-is-the-coldfusion-code-to-upload-a-file-in-amazon-s3-api).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% I understand your questin, but here's how you set a variable:

```
<cfset s3_target_directory = "my directory" />
```

And you output it like this:

```
<cfoutput>#s3_target_directory#</cfoutput>
```

If that's not what you're after, you're going to have to provide more detail in your question.

Comment: Dan, yeah thats what I have to do, exactly what you put in your example, because I am working on a ColdFusion code to load a file into Amazon S3 API.  here please take a look at the sample code I have and maybe it will make more sense to you.

Comment: I apologize for the novice way of asking my question, I am just confused, I need to set the variables for INPUT and variables for OUTPUT.  So that example you have given me, thats what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
Variables
    INPUT:
        variables.s3_target_directory
        variables.file_name
        variables.file_location

    OUTPUT:
        variables.success
        variables.transactionid / success UUID
        variables.s3_location   - link can be http or https
```

// IMPORTANT: Set your key, accesskey and bucket here
                        Variables.accessKeyId = "";
                        Variables.secretAccessKey = "";
                        Variables.BucketName='cic-audio'; // Put your bucket name here